# Laravel Query Value Need To Explode

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have a laravel Query, where it has a value, I need to explode the value and write a where condition.

Here is the code

```
 dd($appointments->whereIn([explode(' ','preference->appoint_info->location_dropdown')],'ssss')->get());
```

Can someone help me with these
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```php
whereIn('ssss', explode(' ','preference->appoint_info->location_dropdown'))
```

The first argument is the `column` name, afterwards the array. Please note, `explode()` already returns an array so there is no need to wrap the call in `[...]`

You can read more about these type of queries in the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

**Another problem:**
`'preference->appoint_info->location_dropdown'` is a string. I guess you want to load a string from somewhere else. So you will need to get the correct data here as well...
I assume it will be `$preference->appoint_info->location_dropdown` but this one is on you

Comment: hi, ssss is a string

Comment: @Ilhamzac yes I saw that. What is this for?  The column name is normally a string and is the first argument.

Comment: preference->appoint_info->location_dropdown - this is the column name, 
i need to explode column name and == to a string

Comment: Why do you need to explode the column name?

Comment: sorry not column

Comment: +"id": "a3f81160-81fa-11eb-bc69-273474788a80"
      +"preference": "{"userinfo": {"dob_": {"day": "01", "year": "1992", "month": "02"},  "email": "jj@.c", "fname": "j", "lname": "j", "mname": "j", "_token": "TMsAYroACMUYWVrxBepWc1zVDBwZuM9Moc3740Zc", "action": "participant", "gender": "Male", "postcode": "m", "ethnicity": "Indian", "street_no": "m", "home_phone": "999999999999", "postal_code": "j", "street_name": "m"}, "enumeration": "false", "appoint_info": {"_token": "TMsAYroACMUYWVrxBepWc1zVDBwZuM9Moc3740Zc", "any_day": "on", "any_time": "on", "location_dropdown": "norwood_hall"}} ◀"

Comment: Please add all the necessary information to your original post. Otherwise the question is not answerable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239250/discussion-between-ilhamzac-and-aless55).